# Reduction to proof undecidability of the problem: machine M and N accept infinitely many words

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, undecidability, halting-problem

I am struggling with the following problem: 
Decide whether this problem is decidable or not: For two given Turing Machines M and N, there exists infinitely many words accepted by both machine M and machine N. In other words, is language `{ encodedMachine(M)#encodedMachine(N) | intersection of language of M and language of N is infinite }` decidable?

Intuitively it feels like this is undecidable problem and halting reduction might be used to proof this, but I have no idea how to start this reduction.

Comment: Hint: Take $M=N$ to be machines ignoring their inputs.

Comment: Your problem is actually $\Pi_2$-complete, making it more difficult than the halting problem.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus, thank you for the tip, but I am not sure if I understand. Let's take a machine for example. Machine K and alphabet {a, b}. Machine K accepts any words made with a (a, aa, aaa, aaaa....), but it loops when first letter is `b`. So it doesn't have halting property, but it accepts infinitely many words.

Comment: On the other hand, I also don't see how to distinguish answer "doesn't accept infinitely many words". Let's assume M loops always -> then it doesn't accept infinitely many words.  Let's assume machine accepts word `aba` and rejects other words, then we get same answer `it doesn't accept infinitely many words`

Comment: Or maybe I didnt understand the part `machines ignoring their inputs.`. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Ok, maybe I have an idea now. For halting problem instance, we have machine M and input x. Now we construct machine M' following way: `M'(y) = Simulate M on input y (ignore original input x). If it accepts -> M' accepts y. If it rejects -> M' accepts y`.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work yet. Because if M loops on one particular input and rejects others, M' will loop on this one particular input but will still accept infinitely many words.

Comment: Aww, I have ignored wrong input, didn't I? Let's try again. For halting problem instance we have machine M and input x – let's contract M' following way: `M'(y) = simulate M on x. Accept` (so we ignore y). Now let's run 'infinietely many words' machine on (M', M') if M halted, M' accepted infinitely many words. If M looped, M' also looped and didn't accept infinitely many words.

Comment: But this time I assumed that M' doesn't accept if M looped, can I assume that?

Comment: Ok, now I see it is ok, because it is not a problem if M' loops. It is a task for a machine from question (which answers infinity or not), to detect if given M and N loop (and therefore not accept the word) or not.

Comment: @Andy, it looks like you have got the idea. (By the way, if M' simulate M and M loops, then there is no way to let M' accept, i.e., M' doesn't accept in that case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reduction from the halting problem, whether a given TM halts on empty input, as given in Yuval's comment.

For a TM $M$, let $K$ be the same as $K$ but ignoring inputs. That is, for any input, $K$ will first erase the input so that it looks like an empty input is given. Then $K$ will simulate $M$ on empty input. When the simulation halts, $K$ accepts. Now consider whether $\langle K\rangle\#\langle K\rangle$ is in the language specified in the question.

**Exercise.** Construction a reduction from the other halting problem, whether a given TM halts on a given input $x$.